# Mysql Query for a room based chat system. Build a list of all rooms

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, chat, distinct

I could need some help with a mysql query for a room based chat application.

The query needs to find all the rooms a user belongs to and order them by the date of the last message submitted into the room.

Only users that are members of a room can read the messages for the room.

Here is a "not working" code but maybe it helps to get the idea of what the query should do:

What the query should do:
a) create a list of all rooms the user is member of ordered by the date of the last message
b) no duplicate rooms ( the query below lists rooms several times if there are multiple messages with different dates... )
c) the result should contain the room_id, the room_name and the date of the last message from this room.

Note/Hint: There will always exists a message. After the room is created the system will add the first message on its own. ( Message 1 for every room: 'Room created on "DATE"' ).

**Buggy query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT cf.room_id, cf.date, cr.room_name
FROM cf_rooms_messages cf
INNER JOIN cf_rooms cr
ON cr.id = cf.room_id
WHERE EXISTS( 
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM cf_rooms_users 
  WHERE user_id = ? 
  AND room_id = cf.room_id 
)
ORDER BY cf.date
DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

**Tablelayouts:**

```
/* this table keeps the room_id and the room_name */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cf_rooms` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `room_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

/* this table keeps the messages submitted into the rooms */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cf_rooms_messages` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `sender_uid` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `msg_text` text NOT NULL,
  `date` int(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

/* this table contains the members of the rooms */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cf_rooms_users` (
  `room_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `added_by_uid` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` int(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Result should look like this:

room_id | room_name | last_message_date

Thanks for your help.

Comment: SELECT '' room_id, '' room_name, '' last_message_date

Answer (score 0):

You can group the results by the user and room, and get just the last (max) date from the messages in a "room". Then you just order the results to show the rooms by last message date.

Not tested, but it should be something like:

```
SELECT
    a.`user_id` as `user_id`,
    b.`room_name` as `room_name`,
    MAX(c.`date`) as `last_msg_date`
FROM `cf_rooms_users` a
JOIN `cf_rooms_rooms` b
ON a.`room_id` = b.`id`
JOIN `cf_rooms_messages` c
ON a.`user_id` = c.`sender_uid`
WHERE a.`id` = this_user_id
GROUP BY a.`user_id`, b.`room_name`
ORDER BY MAX(c.`date`) DESC, b.`room_name`;
```

Replace *this_user_id* with the ID of the user you want to create the list of.

Comment: Thanks. Unknown column a.id. If I change it to a.user_id it throws following error:  #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: My mistake. Leave out the MAX(c.`date`) in the group by clause

Comment: I would also suggest using timestamp instead of the int(12) for the dates. That way you could select by date (ignore time) ranges, months, etc. Also, make the ID fields AUTO_INCREMENT and primary keys.